# PHP - Good design pattern for static database connection class

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have a "static" class which connects to database and has various functions. The current base layout is as follows:

```
class DB {

    private static $con;

    private function __construct() {};

    private static function init() {
        if(is_null(self::$con) {
            // Initialize database connection
        }
    }

    public static someMethod1() {
        self::init();
        // Do stuff
    }

    public static someMethod2() {
        self::init();
        // Do stuff
    }

    public static someMethod2() {
        self::init();
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

My intention is to be easily be able to call these methods as: `DB::someMethod1()`. However, as you can see, I am having to cehck for initialization at every method beginning. Is this a good coding practice? Is there a better design pattern available? Initially I thought of builder pattern but that doesn't really fit here in my opinion.

Comment: Use Doctrine. What you are trying is all already done, better and by better developers than me and you toghether :)

Comment: Does this code compile/runnable? Can you call an instance method inside a static method? Anw, using static class/method like this may be an anti-pattern. It would be difficult to test other classes that use your Db class.

Comment: @Kata my bad, forgot `static` keyword there while I was "insulating" the code. Thanks @Aerendir, will look into it

Comment: If you want to be able to call any one of its methods without knowing if the connection's already been initialized, then -- whether static or not, you don't necessarily make a connection in a constructor -- each of your methods is going to have to check it. Typically you'd be aware of having initialized the connection before you start calling methods, wouldn't you. And your `init` method should probably be checking for `is_null(self::$con)` instead.

Comment: Ah, adjusting to php is gonna be funny coming from all strictly typed languages. I have been making so many mistakes with variable names just because it creates a new variable instead of assigning to old one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to ensure that there is a single instance of your DB class AND also that the instance is available as a single, globally available constant.

I'd recommend separating those two concerns in order to simplify the implementation.

First, I'd focus on getting the database access object right. Plain objects are simpler to test and inject as dependencies than static functions. For example,

```
class DBThing
{
    private $con;

    public static function build()
    {
        return new static('theconnection');
    }

    function __construct($con)
    {
        $this->con = $con;
    }

    public function someMethod1()
    {
        echo "someMethod1: $this->con\n";
    }

    public function someMethod2()
    {
        echo "someMethod2: $this->con\n";
    }

    public function someMethod3()
    {
        echo "someMethod3: $this->con\n";
    }
}
```

Gives you an object you can easily test and replace with alternate implementations if needed.

Second, I'd focus on the object lifecycle and making it discoverable in the application.

If you're really OK with a single instance and the global state that implies, then something like this gets you close to the interface you asked for in your original post.

```
$DB = DBThing::build();

$DB->someMethod1();
$DB->someMethod2();
$DB->someMethod3();
```

In general, I discourage global state but I'd have to know more about your application to know if it's appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a simple db class for a coding test. Take a look at how I used here: https://github.com/TheRealJAG/Valuation-Vision-Full-Stack-Test/blob/master/classes/db.php

```
class DB
{
    private static $instance = null;
    private $db;
    private $host = '';
    private $username = '';
    private $password = '';
    private $database = '';

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
        if ($this->db->connect_error) {
            throw new Exception("Connection to the mysql database failed: " . $this->db->connect_error);
        }
    }

    public static function connection()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance->db;
    }
}
```

I'm 100% sold on the approach, but with the time I had for the test this is what I wrote. My biggest concern was that I only had 1 db connection open.